# Javascript call one object method after another

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
const Foo = {

  bar(x) {

  },

  baz(x) {

  },

}
```

How can I rewrite this object to be able to call it's methods like this:

```
Foo.bar(x).baz(y);
```

instead of calling them like this:

```
Foo.bar(x);
Foo.baz(y);
```

---

Like in the `jQuery` where you can call one function after another...

`$('bac').addClass('x').removeClass('y');`

Comment: define `bar` to return `this` or `Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `this` at the end of each function. In this context `this` refers to the `Foo` object itself.

```
const Foo = {

  bar(x) {
      return this;
  },

  baz(z) {
      return this;
  }

}
```

Example:

```
Foo.bar(x).baz(z);
```

is executed as:

```
Foo.bar(x) // <-- returns 'Foo'
   .baz(z) // <-- call 'baz' function of 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 5):

You will have to return the object itself with each function, so as you could call the function on it again (that's also what jQuery does).

```
const Foo = {

  bar(x) {
     return this;
  },

  baz(x) {
     return this;
  },

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a [Fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) API

> In software engineering, a fluent interface (as first coined by Eric Evans and Martin Fowler) is an implementation of an object oriented API that aims to provide more readable code.
>   A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method cascading (concretely method chaining)

In this case it is implemented by returning the self-object `this`:

```js
const foo = {

    bar(x) {
        console.log("bar")
        return this; // here
    },

    baz(x) {
        console.log("baz")
        return this; // and here

    }
}

foo.bar(10).baz(20);
```

Comment: Thanks for the definition!

Comment: A very popular approach when building dsl-like apis (and builders). wished it was more used as it also makes lambda expressions easier to write in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Return The Object Itself From The Method To Call Another Method Again:

```js
const Foo = {

  bar(x) {
    alert("BAR");
    return this;
  },

  baz(x) {
    alert("BAZ");
    return this;
  },

}

onload = function() {
  Foo.bar().baz();
}
```

Comment: What does your answer add to the answers already provided here?